# Angular NPM Install - error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2017 (Platform Toolset = 'v141'

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I got an error like below, when I try to npm i to my Angular project.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\ Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(439,5):
> error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2017 (Platform
> Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build
> tools,  please install Visual Studio 2017 build tools.
> Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by
> selecting the  Project menu or right-click the solution, and then
> selecting "Retarget solution"

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I followed a path as follows and the problem was resolved.
When I did npm i installed the packages without any problems.

I was able to solve this by reinstalling the UWP tools from the VS2019 package manager, and carefully selecting everything on the right panel. Then on VS I've selected the project -> properties -> general (for all configuration) and selected as platform toolset the value Visual Studio 2017 (v141)

[image]